# Insert an image into a DIV based on click position

Tags: jquery

I am trying to insert an image in a `div` based on where the user clicks. This seems to work fine, unless the `div` is scrollable, and then the position of the image remains the same regardless of where we've scrolled to. The image should remain in the same place relative to the content within the `div`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kDSLg/1/)

Code:

```
$("#a").on("click",function(e){

    var top=e.pageY-$(this).position().top,
        left=e.pageX-$(this).position().left;

    $('.imgajoutee').remove();
    $(this).append("<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0c/Dive_hand_signal_OK_1.png' class='imgajoutee' style='top:"+top+"px;left:"+left+"px;'/>");

});
```

Comment: http://smoothdivscroll.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you'll need to do:

- Change your `img` CSS so that it's `position` value is `absolute` rather than `fixed`
- You'll also need to change your container (in this case `#a`) to have a `position:relative`
- Finally, your calculation for `top` should be changed to use `.offset()` instead of `position()` and also add the `.scrollTop()` value for the container. This calculates how much the container has been scrolled.

With all these things considered, [see updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kDSLg/15/):

**CSS**

```
#a { position:relative; }
img { position: absolute; }
```

**JS**

```
$("#a").on("click",function(e) {
    var top = $(this).scrollTop() + e.pageY - $(this).offset().top,
        left = e.pageX-$(this).offset().left;
    ...
});
```

Comment: This is broken... I'm updating.

Comment: Great :) - no problem